# Jest: Automatically collect coverage from tested files

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage

In my application, while developing, I run:

```
npm run test src/components/component.test.tsx
```

This runs the specific test suite for the component I'm working on.
On top of that, I can then change it to:

```
npm run test src/components/component.test.tsx -- --coverage --coverageReporters=text-summary --collectCoverageFrom=src/components/component.tsx
```

Which will print a coverage report for that specific file once the tests have been run.

As you can see this is extremely wordy and only gets worse if I want to test two or three files at the same time.

Is there any way to automate `collectCoverageFrom` to collect coverage from the files that have been tested (not from all files in the project) so that I don't have to type it out manually every single time?

Answer (score 3):

Just omit the "collectCoverageFrom" (or explicitly set it to an empty glob if you're overriding the config file).

Jest will then only collect coverage from files that are used during the test run.